# How create Menu items by permissions for a view page?

Tags: views, 8, users, navigation

My client wants a menu with a link for each content type.

- Each item will displayed if the user have permission to create that
  content type.
- Each item will show a list of content only for that content type.

To accomplish this, I create a view page that have a filter for bundle. In that way I can use same view page for all content types. I tried too, to use same view page like **/admin/content** but I need to pass the content type to filter for that machine name.

What I trying to do, is create a menu item for each content type, and set permission for each item(link) using the permission that have each content type.

E.g.: My menu have a Item Article. You should see this item only If you have right to create an Article. When you click here you will see all the content Articles(like /admin/content).

**It suppose that a user or role, that have permission to create a content type.. should see the item.**

**How can I create menu items with permission to a view?**

There is my issue, because it use the permission in the view page, and not in the route.

[image]

.links.menu.yml

```
content_types.admin_1:
 title: 'Articles'
 parent: content_types.admin_menu
 route_name: content_types.admin_1
 route_parameters:
  type: article
 description: 'Content articles'

content_types.admin_2:
 title: 'News'
 parent: content_types.admin_menu
 route_name: content_types.admin_2
 route_parameters:
  type: nouvelle
 description: 'Content news'
```

.routing.yml

```
content_types.admin_1:
  path: '/admin/view-test'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'Articles'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'create article content'

content_types.admin_2:
  path: '/admin/view-test'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'News'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'create nouvelle content'
```

As you see I added _permission: 'create article content' but it didn't do anything.

admin/structure/views/view/view_test?destination=/en/admin/structure/views

[image]

The role for the user that I'm using doesn't have permission to create article or news.

**UPDATED:**

I created a .permissions.yml and used _permission: 'access menu item 1' but it display the item even if this permission is not ticket for that role.

.permissions.yml

```
'access menu item 1':
  title: Access Menu MTL 1
  description: Allow users to access menu MTL
```

Any suggestion?

**UPDATED: January, 2019**

The issue is try to use same view page(/admin/content) for each Content type with different permissions. You dont set permissions to each link, instead you set permission to the view (or item) that you are trying to access.

Comment: Have you defined your permissions in a `.permissions.yml` file? Please see http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2016/02/21/dynamic-permissions-in-drupal-8

Comment: not, I think those permissions are created when content type are created, or not?

Comment: No, the ones you're using are not defined. You can check in the permissions page for the correct names created by Node module

Comment: I see this : 'Article: Create new content' but .. when I export the config for that role.. it add this  'create article content'

Comment: The entire solution appears a little hackish. Dynamic menu items might help. But maybe I'm just missing your point. For a good answer, it would be of help for you to add some further information about what your overall goals are, and why you use a view instead of menus/local tasks.

Comment: @mario To resume the goal, the client want an item for each content type. But, it will displayed if the user have permission to create content for that CT. This item will link to a view filter only for that bundle.

Comment: Re-edit your question accordingly. Add as many details as you can provide. E.g., as introduction to why you did what you did. I still find that dynamic menu items is what you're looking for. Maybe I can give you a short example when having tomorrow's morning coffee and enough details.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I re-edited the question. I'll check dynamic menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I did:**

I tried using dynamic menus. But it isn't functional for my purpose. Because, each link menu could have different access by roles.

Then I realized that I needed to create a view for each type of content to be able to manage an individual permission.

Therefore I need to create a view each time that I create a CT, so the is no sense to do it dynamically.

**How I did:**

1. I create a view for each CT with a filter content by type. And also I set permission for each view for same CT. And a custom route.
   [image]
2. Create one item menu for each CT and set as route same as is in the view.

.links.menu.yml

```
    vdm.tc_sujet:
     title: 'Sujets'
     parent: system.admin_content
     route_name: vdm.tc_sujets
     description: "Content type subject."
     weight: -1
```

.routing.yml

```
    vdm.tc_sujets:
     path: '/admin/content/sujet'
     defaults:
       _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
       _title: 'Sujets'
```

3. As result if user have access to that view the item menu will be displayed.

[image]

**Note**: I think that dynamic menus it fix great for add link item to nodes.